# Alembic creates table in default "postgres" data base instead of the existing database

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, sqlalchemy, fastapi, alembic

I have a fast api app used to handle data base migrations with alembic and sql alchemy as per this example:

https://github.com/nf1s/fastapi_sqlalchemy_alembic/blob/master/alembic/env.py

The .env file in my alembic directory looks like this :

```
from logging.config import fileConfig

from sqlalchemy import engine_from_config
from sqlalchemy import pool

from alembic import context

# Loading .env variables in order to inject postgres db url into configuration
import os, sys
from dotenv import load_dotenv

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))
sys.path.append(BASE_DIR)

# this is the Alembic Config object, which provides
# access to the values within the .ini file in use.
config = context.config

# this will overwrite the ini-file sqlalchemy.url path
# with the path given in the config of the main code
config.set_main_option("sqlalchemy.url", os.environ["OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL"])

# Interpret the config file for Python logging.
# This line sets up loggers basically.
if config.config_file_name is not None:
    fileConfig(config.config_file_name)

# add your model's MetaData object here
# for 'autogenerate' support
# from myapp import mymodel
# target_metadata = mymodel.Base.metadata

import models
from models import *

target_metadata = models.Base.metadata

# other values from the config, defined by the needs of env.py,
# can be acquired:
# my_important_option = config.get_main_option("my_important_option")
# ... etc.


def run_migrations_offline() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'offline' mode.

    This configures the context with just a URL
    and not an Engine, though an Engine is acceptable
    here as well.  By skipping the Engine creation
    we don't even need a DBAPI to be available.

    Calls to context.execute() here emit the given string to the
    script output.

    """
    url = config.get_main_option("sqlalchemy.url")
    context.configure(
        url=url,
        target_metadata=target_metadata,
        literal_binds=True,
        dialect_opts={"paramstyle": "named"},
    )

    with context.begin_transaction():
        context.run_migrations()


def run_migrations_online() -> None:
    """Run migrations in 'online' mode.

    In this scenario we need to create an Engine
    and associate a connection with the context.

    """
    connectable = engine_from_config(
        config.get_section(config.config_ini_section, {}),
        prefix="sqlalchemy.",
        poolclass=pool.NullPool,
    )

    with connectable.connect() as connection:
        context.configure(
            connection=connection, target_metadata=target_metadata
        )

        with context.begin_transaction():
            context.run_migrations()


if context.is_offline_mode():
    run_migrations_offline()
else:
    run_migrations_online()
```

My models.py file looks like this:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, String
Base = declarative_base()
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    first_name = Column(String,)
    last_name = Column(String)
    age = Column(Integer)
```

My alembic.ini file looks like this:

```
# A generic, single database configuration.

[alembic]
# path to migration scripts
script_location = alembic

# template used to generate migration file names; The default value is %%(rev)s_%%(slug)s
# Uncomment the line below if you want the files to be prepended with date and time
# see https://alembic.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/tutorial.html#editing-the-ini-file
# for all available tokens
# file_template = %%(year)d_%%(month).2d_%%(day).2d_%%(hour).2d%%(minute).2d-%%(rev)s_%%(slug)s

# sys.path path, will be prepended to sys.path if present.
# defaults to the current working directory.
prepend_sys_path = .

# timezone to use when rendering the date within the migration file
# as well as the filename.
# If specified, requires the python-dateutil library that can be
# installed by adding `alembic[tz]` to the pip requirements
# string value is passed to dateutil.tz.gettz()
# leave blank for localtime
# timezone =

# max length of characters to apply to the
# "slug" field
# truncate_slug_length = 40

# set to 'true' to run the environment during
# the 'revision' command, regardless of autogenerate
# revision_environment = false

# set to 'true' to allow .pyc and .pyo files without
# a source .py file to be detected as revisions in the
# versions/ directory
# sourceless = false

# version location specification; This defaults
# to alembic/versions.  When using multiple version
# directories, initial revisions must be specified with --version-path.
# The path separator used here should be the separator specified by "version_path_separator" below.
# version_locations = %(here)s/bar:%(here)s/bat:alembic/versions

# version path separator; As mentioned above, this is the character used to split
# version_locations. The default within new alembic.ini files is "os", which uses os.pathsep.
# If this key is omitted entirely, it falls back to the legacy behavior of splitting on spaces and/or commas.
# Valid values for version_path_separator are:
#
# version_path_separator = :
# version_path_separator = ;
# version_path_separator = space
version_path_separator = os  # Use os.pathsep. Default configuration used for new projects.

# set to 'true' to search source files recursively
# in each "version_locations" directory
# new in Alembic version 1.10
# recursive_version_locations = false

# the output encoding used when revision files
# are written from script.py.mako
# output_encoding = utf-8

sqlalchemy.url =


[post_write_hooks]
# post_write_hooks defines scripts or Python functions that are run
# on newly generated revision scripts.  See the documentation for further
# detail and examples

# format using "black" - use the console_scripts runner, against the "black" entrypoint
# hooks = black
# black.type = console_scripts
# black.entrypoint = black
# black.options = -l 79 REVISION_SCRIPT_FILENAME

# Logging configuration
[loggers]
keys = root,sqlalchemy,alembic

[handlers]
keys = console

[formatters]
keys = generic

[logger_root]
level = WARN
handlers = console
qualname =

[logger_sqlalchemy]
level = WARN
handlers =
qualname = sqlalchemy.engine

[logger_alembic]
level = INFO
handlers =
qualname = alembic

[handler_console]
class = StreamHandler
args = (sys.stderr,)
level = NOTSET
formatter = generic

[formatter_generic]
format = %(levelname)-5.5s [%(name)s] %(message)s
datefmt = %H:%M:%S
```

My main.py looks like this:

```
import uvicorn
from fastapi import FastAPI
import os
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import DBSessionMiddleware
from fastapi_sqlalchemy import db
from models import User as ModelUser
from schema import User as SchemaUser
from dotenv import load_dotenv

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
load_dotenv(os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ".env"))

app = FastAPI()
app.add_middleware(DBSessionMiddleware, db_url=os.environ["OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL"])


@app.post("/user/", response_model=SchemaUser)
def create_user(user: SchemaUser):
    db_user = ModelUser(
        first_name=user.first_name, last_name=user.last_name, age=user.age
    )
    db.session.add(db_user)
    db.session.commit()
    return db_user


if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

And finally I have a .env file with my db url:

OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:5432

The url points to a postgres docker container that has a database called "test_db", created with the following docker-compose code:

```
db:
    image: postgres:11
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
      - POSTGRES_DB=test_db
```

When I create a revision with auto generate and then run a migration, the table is created in a database called "postgres", and I can't see where this is specified in the configuration. I would like to be able to choose which database is being targeted and update "test_db" but have only found configuration at the server level (the db url).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This `OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:5432` is incomplete if you want to point at `test_db`. To do that modify to `...@db:5432/test_db`. See here [Connection strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) *34.1.1.2. Connection URIs*. Without an explicit database name the database name used will be equal to the user name, in this case `postgres` per [Connection keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).

Comment: @Adrian Klaver that did the trick. Post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

`OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:5432`

is incomplete if you want to point at test_db.

To do that modify to:

`OPERATIONAL_DATABASE_URL = postgresql+psycopg2://postgres:postgres@db:5432/test_db`

See here [Connection strings](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-CONNSTRING) Section *34.1.1.2. Connection URIs*. Without an explicit database name the database name used will be equal to the user name, in this case postgres per [Connection keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS).